# Unitttest, no test result

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

Anybody please help me why I cannot see the output result of the test in shell. Enclosed are the module code and test file both saved in the directory. Thanks a lot, and can anybody help me with a good textbook for python testing for beginners.

I wrote to shell: python calculate_test.py -v

**calculate.py** : this should be the module file

```
class Calculate(object):
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    calc = Calculate()
    result = calc.add(2, 2)
    print result
```

**calculate_test.py**: this is the test file

```
import unittest
from app.calculate import Calculate  #this is maybe the problem


class TestCalculate(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.calc = Calculate()

    def test_add_method_returns_correct_result(self):
        self.assertEqual("HelloWorld", self.calc.add("Hello", "World"))
```

Comment: So what is your test output?

Comment: Ah, ok, you didn't run the test. You should call `python -m unittest calculate_test.py`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it : python -m unittest calculate_test.py and it gives me this: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'py'

Comment: Alternatively, you can also add `if __name__ == '__main__': unittest.main()` in your test file and just run the file.

Comment: Or running `python -m unittest calculate_test.TestCalculate' should also work. Make sure you are in the correct path.

Comment: Great, I had to add if __name__ == '__main__': unittest.main() to test file and wrote python -m unittest calculate_test.TestCalculate to prompt. Now its working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Look of test file:

```
import unittest
from calculate import Calculate   #calculate is file-module, method from module


class TestCalculate(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.calc = Calculate()

def test_add_method_returns_correct_result(self): #testcase1
    self.assertEqual("HelloWorld", self.calc.add("Hello", "World"))

def test_correct_result(self): #testcase2
    self.assertEqual(5, self.calc.add(2,2))


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    unittest.main()
```

To run the test at command line:

```
python -m unittest test_calculate.TestCalculate
```